# error in export CSV in R Using write.csv()

Tags: r

I got this error after runing write.csv(),

how I can fix it?

Thanks

```
write.csv (res_basic,"ceRNA_basic_result", row.names=TRUE)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 43131, 10499
```

str(res_basic):

```
List of 2
 $ cesig   :'data.frame':   43131 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ targetce  : chr [1:43131] "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" ...
  ..$ anotherce : chr [1:43131] "ADGRG1" "AFAP1" "BCL3" "C1orf147" ...
  ..$ miRNAs    : chr [1:43131] "hsa-miR-6837-3p" "hsa-miR-1185-1-3p" "hsa-miR-6837-3p" "hsa-miR-1185-1-3p" ...
  ..$ miRNAs_num: num [1:43131] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ratio     : num [1:43131] 0.5 1 1 1 1 0.5 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ cenotsig:'data.frame':   10499 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ targetce  : chr [1:10499] "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" "AASDHPPT" ...
  ..$ anotherce : chr [1:10499] "ARCN1" "BACH1" "CDK6" "DNAJA1" ...
  ..$ miRNAs    : chr [1:10499] "hsa-miR-1185-1-3p" "hsa-miR-1185-1-3p" "hsa-miR-7849-3p" "hsa-miR-6837-3p" ...
  ..$ miRNAs_num: num [1:10499] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ ratio     : num [1:10499] 0.333 0.25 0.2 0.333 0.333 ...
```

Comment: can you show the `str(res_basic)`.

Comment: `write.csv` expects a `data.frame` but your `res_basic` isn't a `data.frame`, it's a `list` (of two `data.frame`s)

Comment: I need to export this list as file, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a `list` of `data.frame`.  Thus, we need to loop if we want to write as two separate datasets

```
Map(function(x, y) write.csv(x, paste0(y, ".csv"), row.names = TRUE),
     res_basic, names(res_basic))
```

---

If it needs to be a single file, bind them together into a single data and then write it back

```
library(dplyr)
write.csv(bind_rows(res_basic, .id = 'grp'), 
    "ceRNA_basic_result.csv", row.names=TRUE)
```